# Pull the top three items from the database in php

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I am trying to pull a list of genres from the database. I enter a list of genres into the database for each song, and then it (is supposed to) pull each song's genre into a list and order them by the top three most common occurrences.

The genres get put into a single text field in such a fashion:

(basic fashion, not an actual result):

```
blues rock, garage rock, hard rock
```

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `song_name`, `song_genres` FROM `songs` WHERE `album_id` = '$songAlbumId'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $song_name = $row['song_name'];
    $song_genres = explode(", ", $row['song_genres']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($song_genres); $i++){
        $count=array_count_values($song_genres);//Counts the values in the array, returns associatve array
        arsort($count);//Sort it from highest to lowest
        $keys=array_keys($count);//Split the array so we can find the most occuring key
        echo $keys[$i] . "<br>";

    }   
}
```

This ends up giving me:

```
Hard Rock
Garage Rock
Hard Rock
Garage Rock
Psychedelic Rock
Blues Rock
Garage Rock
Hard Rock
```

Also note there is nothing wrong with the album id or anything else. It is specifically to do with just the genres being ordered right.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` statement

Comment: @u_mulder, does that work the way I used it. Comments may be seperated by commas, but when it comes out of the database, it is just a long string. Does `GROUP BY` work for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a couple days trying to figure it out. I ended up reworking the database and posting the songs genres into a database for the song, album, and band sections to easily pull from.

For anyone in the future who wants help with a problem like this, the solution is here: [Merge multiple arrays into one array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312121/merge-multiple-arrays-into-one-array).

I appreciate the input from the other people though.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize the genres. Use a `genres` table instead of a comma separated list, and an additional `songs_genres` table to link songs to genres. Then you can get the data from the database without further logic in php

```
SELECT g.name, COUNT(DISTINCT(sg.song_id)) cnt
FROM genres g
INNER JOIN songs_genres sg ON sg.genre_id = g.id
GROUP BY g.name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Would the `songs_genres` table link a song to multiple genres? If so then grand, if not then why have two extra tables when the OP could use a numbering system to put in his songs table that is a foreign key to the genres table?

Comment: @BigChris `songs_genres` provides an N:M link between songs and genres.

Comment: That's what I thought. Good that you thought of the n:m as this may give the OP additional ideas to be able to put a song into multiple genres, rather than their existing setup

Answer (score 0):

You need another loop so your genres echo for each songname

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $song_name = $row['song_name'];
    $song_genres = explode(", ", $row['song_genres']);

foreach($song_name as $songname){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($song_genres); $i++){
        $count=array_count_values($song_genres);//Counts the values in the array, returns associatve array
        arsort($count);//Sort it from highest to lowest
        $keys=array_keys($count);//Split the array so we can find the most occuring key
        echo $keys[$i] . "<br>";

    }   
                                }
}
```